# How can I search whole word not partial match in string in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to replace a word in a string. The below code does the replacing job, but it also replaces partial match which I don't want it to do.

```
If InStr(inputString, "North") Then
    inputString = Replace(inputString, "North", "N")
End If
```

This code replaces north with N, which is great, but it also replaces Northern with Nern, which I don't want. How can I compare only the whole word?

In php it's `==` but I am not sure in VBA, by the way I am using this in MS Access VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go like this

```
If InStr(inputString, "North") Then inputString = Trim(Replace(Replace(Replace(inputString & " ", " North ", "  North  "), " North ", " N"), "  ", " "))
```

which is the "contraction" of

```
If InStr(inputString, "North") Then
    inputString = inputString & " " '<-- add a space at the end to catch "North" should it be the last "word" in a possible "...North" string
    inputString = Replace(inputString, " North ", "  North  ") '<-- double spaces before and after any " North " occurrence, necessary for subsequent statement to properly work should there be more than one " North " occurrence
    inputString = Replace(inputString, " North ", " N") '<-- make the "core" replacement
    inputString = Replace(Replace(inputString, " North ", " N"), "  ", " ") '<-- make all double spaces occurrences as single ones
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to what you asked

```
Public Function WordMatch(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Word As String) As Boolean
Dim RightChar As String
Dim LeftChar As String
Dim IStart As Integer
Dim IEnd As Integer
Dim Flag As Boolean
Dim Alphabet As String
 Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 Flag = True

IStart = InStr(Text, Word)

If Not (IStart > 0) Then
    Flag = False
Else
    IEnd = IStart + Len(Word) - 1

    If (IStart = 1 And IEnd = 1) Then GoTo WordMatched

        If IStart > 1 Then
            LeftChar = Mid(Text, IStart - 1, 1)
            'LeftChar = Mid(Text, IStart - 1 - 3, 4)
            'MsgBox "L'" & LeftChar & "' - " & Text & " - " & Word
            If InStr(Alphabet, LeftChar) > 0 Then
                Flag = False
            End If
        End If
        If (IEnd < Len(Text)) Then
            RightChar = Mid(Text, IEnd + 1, 1)
            'RightChar = Mid(Text, IEnd + 1, 4)
            'MsgBox "R'" & RightChar & "' - " & Text & " - " & Word
            If InStr(Alphabet, RightChar) > 0 Then
                Flag = False
            End If
        End If

    'End If

End If
```

WordMatched:
    WordMatch = Flag
End Function